# Remove specific screen from NavigationView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

Currently i am using **NavigationView->NavigationLink** to navigate one screen to another. How can i remove specific screen from NavigationView?

For Example I have four screen A, B, C and D. The navigation chain like this A->B-C->D. From **Screen D** how can i go back in **Screen B** and then **Sceen A**

Comment: Don´t use `NavigationLink/NavigationView` use `NavigationStack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to the new `NavigationStack` for iOS 16 which allows programmatic navigation.

The `NavigationStack` takes a `path` parameter; and array that you add or remove objects to, representing your navigation stack. Use the `navigationDestination` modifier to decide which actual views to push on the stack based on the contents of the path.

Example:

```
enum NavView {
    case b, c, d
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var path: [NavView] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Show B", value: NavView.b)
                    .navigationTitle("View A")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: NavView.self) { view in
                switch view {
                case .b: ViewB(path: $path)
                case .c: ViewC(path: $path)
                case .d: ViewD(path: $path)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @Binding var path: [NavView]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Show C", value: NavView.c)
            .navigationTitle("View B")
    }
}

struct ViewC: View {
    @Binding var path: [NavView]
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show D", action: { path.append(NavView.d) })
            .navigationTitle("View C")
    }
}

struct ViewD: View {
    @Binding var path: [NavView]
    var body: some View {
        Button("Back to B", action: { path.removeLast(2) })
            .navigationTitle("View D")
    }
}
```

Note that the `navigationDestination` modifier is *not* on the `NavigationStack`, but one one of its contained views.

[image]

Comment: It works. Thanks. And understood how NavigationStack works.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use either `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` or the new `NavigationStack`. (I am not familiar yet with the latter but I can explain the general concept).

If you use the standard `NavigationLink` it will use a initialiser with a `destination` and a `label`. With this, you are limiting yourself as you are putting the view in control of the navigation. The view will push and pop and you are not in the loop so you can't achieve what you want.

However, you can use a different initialiser to create the `NavigationLink` that uses a binding to a `Bool` that determines if the navigation link is active (i.e. if it is pushed).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(isactive:destination:label:)

(This is deprecated in iOS16 though so it depends on what iOS version you are targeting).

With this you can now use the value of the `isActive` boolean to control the push of the navigation link. So if you have a boolean in your code you can update it and it will make the app pop back to the view you want to.